# starting a service results in error 'Service hold-off time over' - can't find python path

Tags: systemd, services

When I start the service and check immediately the status `sudo systemctl status myservice` it seems to be active and start to run but after a few seconds it moves to `Failed to start service` and it shows

```
 Failed with result exit code
 Service hold-off time over sheduling restart
 Stopped service
 Start request repeated too quickly
 Failed to start service
```

The file:

```
[Unit]
Description=myservice

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /opt/df/run.sh -pidfile=/var/run/myservice.pid
Restart=always
RestartSec=60                       
SyslogIdentifier=myservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

One thing that comes in mind is that in order for the script to start running (the run.sh in /opt/df) , it needs around a minute or more.

I am not sure if this has to do with this problem.

------------ UPDATE ---------------

Hmm..I run `journalctl -xe` and found :

```
Activating virtualenv at .venv
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
   status = self.run(options, args)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in runwb.build(autobuilding=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
     self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
     ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 448, in _prepare_file
     req_to_install, finder)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 387, in _check_skip_installed
     req_to_install.check_if_exists()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1011, in check_if_exists
     self.req.project_name
   AttributeError: 'Requirement' object has no attribute 'project_name'
myservice.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

If I just run the script (the run.sh with no service) :

```
Activating virtualenv at .venv
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement already up-to-date: pip==8.0.2+gx2 in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bx-python==0.7.3 in ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe==0.23 in ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyYAML==3.11 in ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): SQLAlchemy==1.0.8 in ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
....
```

So, it seemd that service cannot find the right python path? ( the anaconda path I am using)??

Comment: Your `run.sh` is terminating after it runs (or backgrounding), so `systemd` thinks your process is dying, and restarts it.  If you want a job that runs once a minute then you should use a _timer_ unit and not a service.  If you _want_ a service then `run.sh` should not die and should stay in the foreground, or the type should be set to `forking`.  Check the OPTIONS section of https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html for more on types.

Comment: @StephenHarris:I  want a service that should stay alive always.Check my update please.Thanks

Comment: Try running your program as root from the command line with `env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin /bin/sh /opt/df/run.sh -pidfile=/var/run/myservice.pid`

Comment: @StephenHarris:It gives me exactly the same error as journal `.....AttributeError: 'Requirement' object has no attribute 'project_name'` .(I 'll be back in a couple of hours.Thank you!)

Comment: So now you know it's not a system unit problem but a problem with your code.  Likely it's expecting environment variables to be set from the environment.  Bad assumption!

Comment: @StephenHarris:Hmm..The script is not mine though.I uploaded [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/zB9BCsD7AzZdWCGWVC8ZZt) a small part of it which I believe does the damage.Do you think you can help me?Thanks!

Comment: Create your own wrapper script that sets the variables you think might be needed (check your current `env` values and pick ones that look like they might be important) and this wrapper calls your final `run.sh` script.  Iterate this test via the `env -i` process (`env -i PATH=...  sh wrapper_script`) until it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43377/discussion-between-george-and-stephen-harris).

Comment: if one of the solution was the one, please write an answer!